# I don't understand this sentence in Baldur's Gate

Tags: commas

> Thus, it was a dark day when King Greneire and his horde of 150,000
>   orcs appeared on the plains outside the Citadel of Many Arrows.
>
> King Obould announced to his followers that this horde had been sent
>   to dislodge them from their home and send them out to be scavengers
>   among the plains.
>
> He vowed that, ***as Gruumsh as his witness***, the Citadel of Many
>   Arrows would slaughter these treacherous orcs "like elves during a
>   festival."

Hello, all. This is from an one of history book in Baldur's Gate.(Video Game)

And I don't understand ***as Grummsh as his witness*** part.

Gruumsh is a fictional Character and a kind of Orc's god.

The King Obould vowed that the Citadel of Many Arrows would slaughter these treacherous orcs "like elves during a festival." (I fully understood.)

But why there is no **verb** in [as Grummsh as his witness] part?

Does this sentence mean, King Obould vowed like Gruumsh vowed to his witness in the past?

Or King Obould vowed to Gruumsh as his witness?

I still don't get it. So would you help me to understand this sentece?

Comment: It's a play on the expression "as God is my witness".  It's a claim of truth, as if swearing on a Bible or some such.

Comment: (I suspect that the substitution of "as" for "is" is a typo.)

Comment: I think there's a missing *w*: Should be "He vowed that, as Grummsh ***was*** his witness ..." This makes more sense than *is* because the statement is in past tense and those two verbs ought to agree, tense-wise.

Comment: Note that most of the virtual "books" in Baldur's Gate use texts sourced from old D&D magazines and modules. Some of that material was known to be poorly proofread. This excerpt is no exception, it was taken from "The North: Guide to The Savage Frontier" published by TSR in 1996.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

*As (blank) as my witness* means that you are swearing upon that particular deity that you will do something.

In other words, you risk incurring the wrath of said deity should you not carry out what you are swearing to do.